# SQL datasource Select Command (On Page Load) not working

Tags: sqldatasource

i created this sql datasource in .aspx page i want to get the select command from code behind

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ShopConnString %>" SelectCommand="" ></asp:SqlDataSource>`

so i wrote this code in code behind

`SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Category";`

its not working

also i tried this code its not working also

```
if (!IsPostBack)    
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Category";

        }
```